# Elasticsearch wildcard and sort it by how exact the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document like this

`[{ name : 'Mark'}, { name : 'Aaron Mark'}, { name : 'Jane'}, { name : 'Mary'}, {'Mark Joseph'}]`

every time i do a wildcard search of name : 'Mar*" it always return this

`[{ name : 'Mark'}, {name : 'Aaron Mark'}, { name : 'Mary'}, {name :'Mark Joseph'}]`

but the result that i want is like this

`[{name : 'Mark'}, {name:'Mark Joseph'}, {name:'Mary'}, {name:'Aaron Mark'}]`

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the first line represents five sample documents, not a single one, correct? If yes, it's probably a scoring issue. Can you show us the query your making and the results you get from ES

Comment: the first line is for the sample documents. the query that i'm making is 
`wildcard : { name : "Mar*" }`. the result that i'm getting is the second line.

Comment: Ok, I'm, interested in seeing the scores you get for each document in the results, too.

Comment: It *seems* you want something more like what the Completion Suggester ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html ) does?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a combination of query as below to get the desired order

```
"bool": {
    "should": [
        {
            "wildcard": {
                "name": {
                    "value": "*Mar*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "prefix": {
                "name": {
                    "value": "Mar*",
                    "boost": 2
                }
            }
        },           
        {
            "term": {
                "name": {
                    "value": "Mar",
                    "boost": 4
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

This may not exactly give the result as you specified 'coz "Mar*" cannot differentiate between "Mark" and "Mary". But it is to give you an idea about what can be done.